# esp32 cam and PIR sensor

Tags: sd-card, esp32, camera

I have tried all the GPIO pins listed here:[image: This is a schematic of the ESP32 cam pinouts. I have tried every one of the GPIO pins with errors in initializing the SD Card]I am following this tutorial to save a picture using the ESP32 cam board. I am trying to add a PIR sensor.
https://randomnerdtutorials.com/esp32-cam-take-photo-save-microsd-card/

whenever I try to use any pins to enable wake on external pin high, there is an error either because of interruption with the camera initiation or sd card.

here is my PIR sensor
https://www.robotshop.com/en/wide-angle-pir-motion-sensor.html?gclid=EAIaIQobChMI0Y7QuaOA4wIVl_5kCh3zYA4OEAQYASABEgJFPvD_BwE[image: PIR sensor schematic]
here is the code I am using

```
    /*********
      Rui Santos
      Complete project details at https://RandomNerdTutorials.com/esp32-cam-    take-photo-save-microsd-card

      IMPORTANT!!! 
       - Select Board "ESP32 Wrover Module"
      - Select the Partion Scheme "Huge APP (3MB No OTA)
    - GPIO 0 must be connected to GND to upload a sketch
    - After connecting GPIO 0 to GND, press the ESP32-CAM on-board RESET  button to put your board in flashing mode

   Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person obtaining a copy
  of this software and associated documentation files.
  The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be included in all
  copies or substantial portions of the Software.
*********/

 #include "esp_camera.h"
 #include "esp_timer.h"
 #include "img_converters.h"
 #include "Arduino.h"
 #include "fb_gfx.h"
 #include "fd_forward.h"
 #include "fr_forward.h"
 #include "FS.h"                // SD Card ESP32
 #include "SD_MMC.h"            // SD Card ESP32
 #include "soc/soc.h"           // Disable brownour problems
 #include "soc/rtc_cntl_reg.h"  // Disable brownour problems
 #include "dl_lib.h"
 #include "driver/rtc_io.h"
 #include <EEPROM.h>            // read and write from flash memory 



    // define the number of bytes you want to access
     #define EEPROM_SIZE 1

     // Pin definition for CAMERA_MODEL_AI_THINKER 
     #define PWDN_GPIO_NUM     32
     #define RESET_GPIO_NUM    -1
     #define XCLK_GPIO_NUM      0
     #define SIOD_GPIO_NUM     26
     #define SIOC_GPIO_NUM     27 

     #define Y9_GPIO_NUM       35
     #define Y8_GPIO_NUM       34
     #define Y7_GPIO_NUM       39
     #define Y6_GPIO_NUM       36
     #define Y5_GPIO_NUM       21
     #define Y4_GPIO_NUM       19
     #define Y3_GPIO_NUM       18
     #define Y2_GPIO_NUM        5
     #define VSYNC_GPIO_NUM    25
     #define HREF_GPIO_NUM     23
     #define PCLK_GPIO_NUM     22

     int pictureNumber = 0;

     void setup() {
       WRITE_PERI_REG(RTC_CNTL_BROWN_OUT_REG, 0); //disable brownout detector

       Serial.begin(115200);
       //Serial.setDebugOutput(true);
       //Serial.println();

       camera_config_t config;
       config.ledc_channel = LEDC_CHANNEL_0;
       config.ledc_timer = LEDC_TIMER_0;
       config.pin_d0 = Y2_GPIO_NUM;
       config.pin_d1 = Y3_GPIO_NUM;
       config.pin_d2 = Y4_GPIO_NUM;
       config.pin_d3 = Y5_GPIO_NUM;
       config.pin_d4 = Y6_GPIO_NUM;
       config.pin_d5 = Y7_GPIO_NUM;
       config.pin_d6 = Y8_GPIO_NUM;
       config.pin_d7 = Y9_GPIO_NUM;
       config.pin_xclk = XCLK_GPIO_NUM;
       config.pin_pclk = PCLK_GPIO_NUM;
       config.pin_vsync = VSYNC_GPIO_NUM;
       config.pin_href = HREF_GPIO_NUM;
       config.pin_sscb_sda = SIOD_GPIO_NUM;
       config.pin_sscb_scl = SIOC_GPIO_NUM;
       config.pin_pwdn = PWDN_GPIO_NUM;
       config.pin_reset = RESET_GPIO_NUM;
       config.xclk_freq_hz = 20000000;
       config.pixel_format = PIXFORMAT_JPEG; 

       if(psramFound()){
         config.frame_size = FRAMESIZE_UXGA; // FRAMESIZE_ +  QVGA|CIF|VGA|SVGA|XGA|SXGA|UXGA
        config.jpeg_quality = 10;
        config.fb_count = 2;
      } else {
        config.frame_size = FRAMESIZE_SVGA;
        config.jpeg_quality = 12;
        config.fb_count = 1;
      }

      // Init Camera
      esp_err_t err = esp_camera_init(&config);
      if (err != ESP_OK) {
        Serial.printf("Camera init failed with error 0x%x", err);
        return;
      }

      //Serial.println("Starting SD Card");
      if(!SD_MMC.begin()){
        Serial.println("SD Card Mount Failed");
        return;
      }

      uint8_t cardType = SD_MMC.cardType();
      if(cardType == CARD_NONE){
        Serial.println("No SD Card attached");
        return;
      }

      camera_fb_t * fb = NULL;

      // Take Picture with Camera
      fb = esp_camera_fb_get();  
      if(!fb) {
        Serial.println("Camera capture failed");
        return;
      }
      // initialize EEPROM with predefined size
      EEPROM.begin(EEPROM_SIZE);
      pictureNumber = EEPROM.read(0) + 1;

      // Path where new picture will be saved in SD Card
      String path = "/picture" + String(pictureNumber) +".jpg";

      fs::FS &fs = SD_MMC; 
      Serial.printf("Picture file name: %s\n", path.c_str());

      File file = fs.open(path.c_str(), FILE_WRITE);
      if(!file){
        Serial.println("Failed to open file in writing mode");
      } 
      else {
        file.write(fb->buf, fb->len); // payload (image), payload length
        Serial.printf("Saved file to path: %s\n", path.c_str());
        EEPROM.write(0, pictureNumber);
        EEPROM.commit();
      }
      file.close();

      // Turns off the ESP32-CAM white on-board LED (flash) connected to GPIO 4
      pinMode(4, OUTPUT);
      digitalWrite(4, LOW);
      rtc_gpio_hold_en(GPIO_NUM_4);

      delay(2000);
      Serial.println("Going to sleep now");
      delay(2000);
      esp_deep_sleep_start();
      Serial.println("This will never be printed");
    }

    void loop() {

    }
```

This is the thing I am trying to add. but no matter which pins i chose there are errors. I can add the error if that would be helpful.

```
esp_sleep_enable_ext0_wakeup(GPIO_NUM_X, level)
```

Comment: A schematic of how you are hooking up the PIR to the esp32 cam board would help.

Comment: @st2000 I added some more info to the OP.

Comment: So, you are using pins other than pin 3 (E32_RST)?  Guessing, most embedded processors generate different vectors (places they go to and start code execution) based on which pins are generating interrupts.  It may be that the libraries you are using only setup an interrupt for pin 3.  As this is all guess work - I'm resisting the temptation to change this comment into an answer.

Comment: I am not seeing a pin 3 (esp32 rst) on this board. Could you point it out. Then you can change this to can answer.

Comment: I am looking at [this schematic](https://i.redd.it/yv050peu22p21.png).  Assuming this is the board you have.  I see a reset switch connected to net ES32_RST.  Which appears at pin 3 of the ESP-32S chip.  Guessing, if  your PIR uses an open collector to ground type output, you might try soldering to the open side of the reset switch.

Comment: Ok I think I see now. I would need to solder it to the esp32-s chip itself. I will provide a high signal to the rst pin 3 via the PIR sensor and it will reset the board? I added an edit to include the schematic of my PIR sensor.

Comment: I don't think that is going to work.  The PIR spec says it will output a high when activated.  And the ESP32 Cam schematic, if accurate, shows K1 making a connection to ground when pushed.  So the PIR is doing the opposite of what you need.  Also, the ESP chip is probably a QFN package is is extremely difficult to solder directly to.  Likely it would be much easier to solder to the push button switch lead.

Comment: Ok I will give it a shot

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95313/discussion-between-david-graff-and-st2000).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Software:

It may be that one of the included libraries (software) you are using depends on pin 3 (E32_RST) of the ESP32 going low in order to operate as expected (wake up and take a picture).  Using an alternate pin may wake up the ESP32 but may not behave as expected.

Hardware:

[This schematic of the ESP32 Camera](https://i.redd.it/yv050peu22p21.png) shows how switch K1 is connected to pin 3 of the ESP32.  There is a capacitor C7 and resistor R6 likely used to mitigate K1 switch bouncing and to pull pin 3 high when switch K1 is not pressed.  When switch K1 is pushed it pulls pin 3 to ground waking up the ESP32 to take a picture.

The PIR specified changes its output to high when activated according to its data sheet.  This is opposite of what the ESP32 needs to see at pin 3 in order to take a picture.  It appears an inverter is needed between the PIR and pin 3 of the ESP32.  An open collector type of inverter would be best as this type of driving circuit can be attached where K1, C7 & R6 come together with out interfering with the their (the existing components') operation.  This is the subject of [this stackexchange question / answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/30238/how-to-invert-a-digital-signal).